# Push data to two different nodes with same id

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to push some data to Firebase using jquery. I works fine but I do not manage to push the data to two different child nodes (ref and ref2) with the same id.

In other words, when I use my code, the data pushed on ref has not the same id as the data pushed in ref2.

I have tried many thing but didnt manage to get the expected result.

```
function retrievedata(){

var iduser = window.user;
var uiduser = iduser.uid;

var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref('productspushed'+'/'+uiduser);
var ref2 = database.ref('products');

  $.get(window.location.href, function(data){ 

  $("tr.woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item.cart_item").each(function(i, obj) {
      const name = $('td.product-name', obj).text();
      const nameok = name.trim();
      console.log(nameok);

      const url = $('a', obj).eq(1).attr('href');
      console.log(url);

      const imgurl = $('img.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail.size-woocommerce_thumbnail', obj).attr('srcset').split(',').pop().trim().split(' ')[0];
      console.log(imgurl);

      const price = $('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount', obj).eq(0).text().replace(/€/, '');
      console.log(price);

      const data = {title: nameok, 
      imgurl: imgurl,
      price: price,
      url: url,
      };

        ref2.push(data);
        ref.push(data);

      })
  })


};
```

I would like to push the data to ref and ref2 with the same id. If you guys could give me a hint it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I have solved my issue:

Thanks @ Marco for showing me the right direction.

```
<script>
    function retrievedata(){

    var iduser = window.user;
    var uiduser = iduser.uid;

    var database = firebase.database();
    var ref = database.ref('productspushed'+'/'+uiduser);
    var ref2 = database.ref('products');

    console.log("connected to firebase");

      $.get(window.location.href, function(data){ 

      $("tr.woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item.cart_item").each(function(i, obj) {
          const name = $('td.product-name', obj).text();
          const nameok = name.trim();
          console.log(nameok);

          const url = $('a', obj).eq(1).attr('href');
          console.log(url);

          const imgurl = $('img.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail.size-woocommerce_thumbnail', obj).attr('srcset').split(',').pop().trim().split(' ')[0];
          console.log(imgurl);

          const price = $('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount', obj).eq(0).text().replace(/€/, '');
          console.log(price);

          const data = {title: nameok, 
          imgurl: imgurl,
          price: price,
          url: url,
          };

          var newProductKey = ref.push().key;


          var updates = {};
          updates['/products/' + newProductKey] = data;
          updates['/productspushed/' + uiduser + '/' + newProductKey] = data;

          return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);


          })
      })


    };

    </script>
```

is the solution to my question

Comment: Glad i could help, can you mark your answer as accepted just so the question doesn't stay open?

Comment: I'll do it ;-) I just need to wait for 9 more hours to be able to do it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use push directly like you are doing, as the docs states (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data?hl=en-us): "Calling push() will return a reference to the new data path, which you can use to get the key or set data to it. The following code will result in the same data as the above example, but now we'll have access to the unique key that was generated"

But at the same page there is your catch:

```
// Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
var newPostRef = postsRef.push();

// Get the unique key generated by push()
var postId = newPostRef.key;
```

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I do not get the result I want. I basically want to save the data in firebase as follows (with the same product id):  the same data should appear like: products/idproduct1/title,price,url   and in productspushed/uiduser/idproduct1/title, price, url.